# I just read pointer and array address arithmetic. But I've gotten mixed up

Tags: c, pointers

Would you please help me understand pointers. I just read pointer and array address arithmetic, so I understand the difference between incrementing what a pointer points to and incrementing where a pointer points, assigning arrays to pointers, and indexing. But I've gotten mixed up.

So in this K&R book it explains that you can modify a pointer to point elsewhere (I concur), but the result is undefined if you assign the location of a string constant to a pointer then try to modify the string contents. So how does strcpy work.

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}
```

If s and t are pointers to the address of an array, then I believe it works because s and t point to arrays, not string constants, and increment down t while s = t != '\0'.
I experimented with the pointers here assigning two arrays to two pointers and then used strcpy

```
main()
{
    char array123[3] = "123";
    char array4[2] = "44";
    char *stringp1 = array123; 
    char *stringp2 = array4;
    strcpy(stringp1, stringp2);
    printf("%s", stringp1);
}
```

I got errors and took an image of the errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfWL9.jpg

So what am I mixing up. I need help.

Comment: Hi. Your code doesn't try to modify a string constant. `array123` is a non-constant array that's initialized by copying literal `"123"` into it.  The problem is you're not allocating space for the trailing nulls. This means `strcpy` never sees a null at the end of `"44"` and keeps trying to copy. That's what's corrupting the stack. Change to `array4[3]` or else `array4[]` (which lets the compiler choose the size, including for the null), and the error should go away.

Comment: If you add `*s = 0;` at the end of `strcpy`, you will at least be *nul-termianting* the string. On pointers, a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. (e..g a pointer *points* to some other object in memory) The *type* controls pointer arithmetic. (e.g. `char *p = "abc"; then `p++` advances by 1-byte to the next char, but `int arr[] = {1, 2, 4}; int *p = arr;` then `p++` advances by 4-bytes to the next `int`). Always make sure you know where your pointers point (e.g. what *valid* address they hold as their value)

Comment: @gene and david I changed [2] to [3] and [3] to [4]. Same errors.

Comment: The code in the image is different to the code in the question. In particular you have the sizes of `array123` and `array4` swapped over, which leads to the crash since you write out of bounds. Also the code in the question attempts to use `%s` with a non-null-terminated array

Comment: @M.M Thanks for helping. I am closing the post bc I found answers and help

Comment: @RenzoM-Svartz do not change the question to incorporate the answers. It makes the answers look wrong/invalid. If you have a follow up question, ask another question. You can refer this question there.

Comment: Note that it is _always_ correct (in a hosted environment) to use one of [`int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1) in the function signature for `main()`; any other signature is at best implementation-defined. If your compiler is not complaining about the signature used in the posted code, enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char array4[2] = "44";
```

Here, `array4` holds an array of characters but it does *not* hold a string.

Why? Because a string is defined as a series of characters whose end is marked with a zero byte. But `array4` has no space for the extra zero byte. So `array4` is not a string.

```
char *stringp2 = array4;
```

Okay, so `stringp2` points to `array4`, an array of characters that is not a string.

```
strcpy(stringp1, stringp2);
```

No good. The second parameter to the `strcpy` function must be the *string* to copy.

You want this:

```
char array4[3] = "44";
```

Now, `array4` is a string, so `stringp2` points to a string and is thus legal to pass as the source pointer to `strcpy`.

Comment: Re "*You want this: `char array4[3] = "44";`*", Well, best to let the compiler decide the size: `char array4[] = "44";`